# Aggregate in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

| ORGANIZATION_ID | BAY_ID | CASCADE_GROUP_ID | DOWNSTEAM_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 100012 | 1 | 2 |
| 1001 | 100014 | 1 | 4 |
| 1001 | 100016 | 1 | 6 |
| 1001 | 100018 | 1 | 8 |

I need to create a view by aggregating the values of the DOWNSTEAM_VALUE column mentioned in the above table. In the below example, the aggregation at the DOWNSTEAM_VALUE  column should happen by looking at the BAY_ID. If in case, the first row containing BAY_ID is 100012, the downstream value should be calculated by adding up the DOWNSTEAM_VALUE  of the current BAY_ID row + remaining DOWNSTEAM_VALUE values in ascending order such as 2+4+6+8 and show like 20  and same goes to next BAY_ID , the downstream value would be 4+6+8=18. Since the last BAY_ID doesn't have any more DOWNSTEAM_VALUE values to add, it should show 8.

| ORGANIZATION_ID | BAY_ID | CASCADE_GROUP_ID | DOWNSTEAM_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 100012 | 1 | 20 |
| 1001 | 100014 | 1 | 18 |
| 1001 | 100016 | 1 | 14 |
| 1001 | 100018 | 1 | 8 |

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language - it doesn't do aggregation. SQL does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM analytic function with windowing clause for that like below.

```sql
select ORGANIZATION_ID
    , BAY_ID
    , CASCADE_GROUP_ID
    , sum(DOWNSTEAM_VALUE)over(
        partition by ORGANIZATION_ID, CASCADE_GROUP_ID
          order by BAY_ID asc 
              ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED
                   FOLLOWING) as DOWNSTEAM_VALUE
from your_table 
;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used the with statement over here ?

Comment: You can ignore it. It is just there for test purposes.

Comment: I removed the with part from my answer.

Comment: I have duplicates in the table, Can you let me know how i can manage ?

Comment: Have you already tried my answer ? Does it work for you ? If you have any others questions, feel free to share with the community.

Comment: yes, it works. But the problem is from the source table, i have duplicates.

Comment: @siddharth thiagarajan: What does this mean? You have two rows for the same ORGANIZATION_ID, BAY_ID, and CASCADE_GROUP_ID? And you want to keep them or delete them from the table? If you want to keep them, what do you want to do with them? Please edit your request and add some sample data for this case and what the result is supposed to look like.

Comment: Yeah, there are two rows with the repeated data, I wanna keep it. But I found a solution to it. 

Thanks @ThorstenKettner